# Aspect annotation for class

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, spring-aspects

I have a custom annotation, that is handled with AOP in Spring boot. It works perfect when I put it above a method, but when I put it above class I am not able to extract its value :(

Annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UserAuthorization {
    
    UserRoleEnum[] userRoles();
    
    String paramName() default "userDetails";
    
    String errorMessage() default "NOT AUTHORIZED";

}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class UserAuthorizationAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(UserAuthorization)")
    public Object validateAuthoritiesAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        UserAuthorization userAuthorization = signature.getMethod().getAnnotation(UserAuthorization.class);
        // Some code
    }

}
```

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai That works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change your aspect to check if the class has annotation

```
   signature.getMethod().getDeclaringClass()
                        .getAnnotation(UserAuthorization.class)
```

- Change you annotation to support both class level and method level annotations

```
   @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
```